# ASP.NET C# Controller - How to store Application Objects using OnResultExecuted method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I am constructing a simple login system. In my global.asax file, I created a method "OnResultExecuted" which is called after the action result executes. My idea is to store the username and password in an Application Object after the action result executes but I am not sure where to call it.

*global.asax*

```cs
    public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        private string username, password;
        public BaseController(string username, string password)
        {
            this.username = username;
            this.password= password;
        }

        protected override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
        {
            // Generate an Application Object
            base.OnResultExecuted(context);
        }
    }
```

In my LoginController.cs file, I want to create the application object upon a successful request.

*LoginController.cs*

```cs
public class LoginController : BaseController
    {
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LoginPOST(string username, string password)
        {
            // Is this how Application Objects are stored?
            // How do I call OnResultExecuted in this ActionResult?
            Application["username"] = username;
            Application["password"] = password;
            return View("Login");
        }
    }
```

*My Issues*

- I am unsure on where to call the "OnResultExecuted" method in the LoginController.cs.
- Is this the correct way to create Application Object to store the user's data? If no, please help!
- I am getting an error on LoginController (from *public class LoginController : BaseController*) which states "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required parameter "username" of BaseController.BaseController(string, string)". I have searched for answers online but none seem to work for my case.
- How do I access the Application Object after it is being stored?

What can I try next?

Comment: _"My idea is to store the username and password in an `Application` object"_ - **Don't**: you should not be using `Application` for this... it's data shared _by everyone_.

Comment: Hi @Dai, yes I understand it is dangerous to store username and password inside. It is just an example. I am actually storing some other parameters like time and date and a counter.

Comment: It's not just about it being "dangerous", it's about it being _incorrect_. This is how you're meant to do authentication and authorization: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/

Comment: The point still stands, `Application` is global. If your data is user-specific, it should be stored in `Session`.

Comment: Well, I would still like to know how to use Application Objects :D Thanks for your input though. If you know how do let me know!

Comment: The `Application` collection in ASP.NET (for .NET Framework) is a holdover from [Classic ASP days](https://www.sitepoint.com/asp-sessions-applications/) (1996-2001) - it should not be used in new application (because it's just the same as a `static` field, except without strong-typing). It's removed entirely in ASP.NET Core. Why waste time learning a dead-end system?